# Problemas com componente select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot

Estou com um problema ao apresentar a minha lista de itens do meu select.

Nesse meu HTML uso o ng-repeat para listar todos os itens, e quando minha tela é carregada meu primeiro e único item é: **{{list.name}}**, quando eu clico nesse item **{{list.name}**, ai carrega a lista de corretamente.

```
<select data-placeholder="Escolha uma Empresa/Filial" multiple chosen
                                style="width: 100%;"
                                ng-model="filtroRequisicao.codigoSistemaUsuariosFiliais"
                                required>
                            <option ng-repeat="list in lista" ng-value="list.id">
                                {{list.name}}
                            </option>
                        </select>
```

Angularjs:

```
$scope.lista = [{}];

    //Carrega as Filiais dos Cooperados
        $scope.loadFiliais = function () {
            var usuario = localStorage.getItem("usuarioAutenticado");
            var objetoUsuario = {};

            objetoUsuario = JSON.parse(usuario);


            $http({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: '/getFiliais',
                data: objetoUsuario
            }).then(function (response) {

                    $scope.lista = response.data;

                    console.log($scope.lista);
                },

                function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    $scope.showNoty('Nenhum dado encontrado.', 'information');
                });
        };

        $scope.loadFiliais();
```

Se alguém puder dar alguma dica, agradeço!

Comment: o objeto usuário possui credenciais do usuário?

Comment: Sim, o objeto possui as credenciais do usuário que está logado, esse objeto eu passo para o angular enviar (PUT) e receber a lista de filiais desse usuário.

Comment: Cuidado, pois guardar isso no client não é seguro

Comment: E qual é a melhor prática para isso?

Comment: Cookies do lado do servidor, validação com OAuth2(meio confuso, mais seguro), digest, etc... Da uma pesquisada nesses paradigmas : )

Comment: Ok, vou procurar sobre! Quanto ao problema corrente, tens alguma dica? Obrigado

Comment: ja tentou preencher esse select de outra forma, como o ngOptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver utilizando o ng-if, onde ele remove o elemento e cria novamente conforme a expressão:

[ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

angular:

Inicia a variável:
`$scope.lista = []`;

chama a função `$scope.listaFiliais();`

html:

```
<select data-placeholder="Escolha uma Empresa/Filial" multiple chosen
                                style="width: 100%;"
                                ng-if="lista.length > 0"
                                ng-model="filtroRequisicao.codigoSistemaUsuariosFiliais"
                                required>
                            <option ng-repeat="list in lista" ng-value="list.id">
                                {{list.name}}
                            </option>
                        </select>
```

Eu não sei se essa é a melhor forma, mas resolveu o problema.